# package labeled protected vs package labeled private in scala

Tags: scala, scope, private, protected

What is the difference between

**`private[SomePackage]`**

and

**`protected[SomePackage]`**

in Scala,Somewhere I see ***private[SomePackage]*** somewhere I see ***protected[SomePackage]***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private[SomePackage]` means, it is visible inside the package only (no modifier in Java)

`protected[SomePackage]` means, it can be seen in sub-classes but only if they are inside `SomePackage`

Comment: Thank you for verifying what I thought